# Getting or ignoring the key for the .ipa file

Tags: reverse-engineering, ipa

I'm trying to download the .ipa file via iptools, it shows an error that a license is needed, is there any way to ignore it or get a key? I understand that maybe this is a complex lesson, maybe someone could suggest articles, books or other. In order to generally understand where and how to start breaking the system. Where do all these "stitched" versions of applications come from and how are they made? Thank you in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.